# How to connect Samsung Galaxy S plus to computer (and Eclipse)

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

After 5 hours i have given up. First thing what i did was just setting usb debugging to true and i thought it should work. But nothing. Device is charging, but that is actualy all what happens. Computer would not even recognize the device. Nothing.

note: On that point i must state that i was testing on my friends phone (same cmputer) week before and it worked like a charm. i have just enabled usb debugging and it has worked with ease.

Back to the problem. Then i have instaled usb drivers for samsung phones, and result was the same. A that point i have found kies. So i've uninstaled drivers, reboot computer, instaled kies and tryed again, but again - nothing.

Any ideas?

Edit: i want to connect my device to eclipse, but now i am just trying how to connect my device to computer

Abt my computer: windows7 64bit

Abt device: Samsung Nexus S plus, android version 2.3.5

Comment: Not really related to programming but you might need to change the USB mode from media to something else.

Comment: well it is, becouse i cant test anything now

Comment: raco - state your programming related question, then.

Comment: I'm guessing you're on Windows? If so, it's almost definitely the driver.

Comment: @noloader - ADB (the android **debug** bridge) is a "development tool" and thus specifically on topic here, though it would help if raco would explicitly state the host system type.

Comment: Chris Stratton - the question is about connecting his Android device to a computer. The question does not mention `adb`.

Comment: @noloader - in fact it is about ADB, as indicated by "First thing what i did was just setting usb debugging to true" which is the procedure for enabling ADB on the phone side.

Comment: Chris Stratton - that's a leap. At best, its something he tried while attempting to connect his Android device to his computer.

Comment: Or instead of bickering amongst yourselves, you could ask raco; without being condescending about it?

Comment: ... for purposes of **debugging** ...  See the initial comment exchange "Not really related to programming " to which raco replied "well it is, becouse i cant test anything now"

Comment: Chris Stratton - again, the question does not state that. Perhaps I'm missing something really obvious here...

Comment: Chris Stratton - perhaps the comment you are referring to has been deleted. I can't find anything you claim to cite (the stuff you put in quotes), and the question has not been edited.

Comment: wow guys youd dont need to argue. I have tryed to connect device to eclipse, but with so many problem i am now just trying that computer would recognize it. After it it will work in eclipse

Comment: raco - what, precisely, are you trying to do? "connect Samsung Galaxy S plus to computer" is kind of vague and appears to be off topic for Stack Overflow. Please add it to your question, and don't post it as a comment.

Comment: connect it to eclipse. But i have just asked more general

Comment: "Eclipse... now i am just trying how to connect my device to computer" - does Windows recognize your device in Device Manager? Or does it show up as a removable drive? Can you run `adb` from the command line? What does `adb devices` return?

Comment: It doesnt recognise it anywhere, so i cant even link it to adb

Answer (score 3):

You should first of all install the driver of your Samsung Galaxy S, **Sumsung kies**, you find it in [here](http://www.samsung.com/fr/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP)

and then plug your device

hope this help

Comment: i have tryed this approach so i could see if i can get some response, but: device said connected and kies saied plug your device...

also i dont need kies, becouse i need development options so it was just experimental approach

Comment: if you want to see your device in eclipse, you need the driver of the device, and then when executing your apps you will see it "development options"

Comment: i know

anyway i am again instaling the kies, coz i think it has the right drivers (i have just uninstaled drivers that i have found).

Answer (score 1):

I had a real pain getting my computer to recognize my device (Nexus 7), I documented my steps

http://caffeinatedgeek.ca/2014/03/04/getting-started-with-android-development/

The key I think was using this android usb driver

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

And/or the Usb Computer Connection setting (MTP vs PTP):

> If nothing is attached, you many need to change the Connection type
> with your computer, on your Android device, go to Settings -> Storage,
> and click the elipses in the top right, you’ll come to this screen,
> try changing between the two modes, one should work. On mine it was
> Camera, others have reported differently.

[image]

Comment: "The key I think was using this android usb driver" - is that a different driver than the one provided in platform tools (I think that's where its installed with the SDK manager)?

Comment: Thank you for ansver, but there are two problems:
1. device is not shown at device manager
2. i cant find USB computer connection. Android version on the phone is 2.3.5, so probably it is not available

Comment: If windows is not detecting a device of any sort, try a a different port and cable.  Even without a driver, *something* should show - just putting the pullup resistor on a USB data line is enough to cause the computer to see there is something there it can't talk to.

Comment: @raco it not showing is the problem I initially had. New drivers and the MTP/PTP swap fixed it.

Comment: I am sure that i have most recent drivers but i dont have MTP/PTP options. If i set USB debuggable to false i can chose in USB settings: mass storage, kies or media player

(Gingerbread os)

Comment: @raco, did you try the drivers I linked?  I thought I had the latest as well, then used the drivers straight from google, and it all started to work.

Comment: i have tryed probably all drivers that i could find. Now i have bought Samsung Galaxy y and it is working with ease. There is something wrong with nexus phones...

Comment: @raco, but did you specifically try the drivers I suggested that are direct from google?  Following the steps in my link that uses Device Manager and "Update Driver Software...".

Comment: yes i did. i have tryed on  computer and nothing. I would sooner manage to plugin a rock than that damn phone.